# val evaluation while reading from stdio in scala

Tags: scala, stdin

This program reads some numbers (each number on a new line) from the std io. I enter the numbers only once!
Now, the value "it" should get evaluated at the point of definition (as opposed to lazy val) and "it" should be replaced by the result of the RHS.

So, by the time the first println(it.size) is called "it" has already been evaluated. Then why does the second call to prinln always return zero? Seems like it tries to read again from the std io and since nothing is read it returns zero.

```
object Test {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val it= io.Source.stdin.getLines().map(_.toInt)
        println(it.size) // prints correct number of lines
        println(it.size) // prints zero always????   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then why does the second call to prinln always return zero

Because [`Source.getLines`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.io.Source@getLines():Iterator[String]) returns an `Iterator[String]`, which you're iterating completely with the invocation of `it.size`, which means the iterator reached it's end. [This is how `size` is defined on `TraversableOnce[A]`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L105) (which `Iterator[A]` extends):

```
def size: Int = {
  var result = 0
  for (x <- self) result += 1
    result
}
```

You'll need to materialize the iterator first if you want to be able to iterate multiple times:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val it = io.Source.stdin.getLines().map(_.toInt).toSeq
  println(it.size)
  println(it.size)
}
```

Note this materialization would cause the entire iterator to be loaded into memory.

Comment: Aha, so the size function transforms the iterator's state. I thought it was just returning an integer and leaving the iterator unchanged. Thanks :)